# Method Create error message on creating a new controller in .NetCore MVC application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

Good day every one
I am facing this error first time, have googled but could not find a solution. Your help in this regard will be appreciated.
I am creating .Net core MVC application. I want to add a controller. I am following these steps

1. Right click Controller folder in solution Add -> Controller MVC
2. Controller with views, using Entity Framework I select the
3. appropriate Model class and Data context class and assign Controller
   name (default)
   When I press the Add button, following error occured(see the attached image):
   There was an error running the selected code generator:
   'Method' Create' in type
   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTransactingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqwlServer, Version=3.1.12.0, Culture=neurtal, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx' dowsnot have an implementation.

[Method Create Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPvAF.png)

Comment: open nuget package manager and update all the packages in one shot, it will fix your issue

Comment: You can share your project.csproj file.

Comment: if application is developed in lower version than version(s) of Nuget Package Manager then on Building the solution, Visual Studio also lowers the available version(s) of installed packages by PM. This was happening in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx vivek and Yinqiu I got the solution.
On my machine .Net Core 3.0 and 5.0 both are installed. When I created the project, it was created in 3.0. While using Nuget Package Manager I added all packages in latest version available i.e 5.0. I simply unloaded the project, edited .csproj file and updated version of .net core from 3.0 to 5.0 (in my case) and again uploaded the project, clean and build the solution and problem is solved.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.